# Restart obj number on enable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn, spawning

I am spawning objects on startup,(maxObj = 75) then destroying Obj's on event and disabling spawner Obj.  When player wants they can re enable spawner.   I need count to start at 0 on enable.  Another 75 obj's spawn and are then destroyed.  etc.  Appreciate any help thanks.

```
enter code here
 private static readonly float _spawnTime = 0.125f;

    [SerializeField]

    private GameObject _asteroidObject = null;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _maxObjects = 0;

    private int _spawnedObjects = 0;

    private float _time = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(_spawnedObjects < _maxObjects)
        {
            if(_time > _spawnTime)
            {
                Instantiate(_asteroidObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                ++_spawnedObjects;
                _time = 0;
            }
            _time += Time.smoothDeltaTime;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch it is quite unclear how a User shall be able to start the spawn again I would recommend to rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in general. They are like little temporary `Update` blocks but easier to control and maintain. It is also more efficient since it doesn't call the `Update` method every frame also when the maxObjects amount is already reached and nothing is going to happen anyway

```
[SerializeField] 
private GameObject _asteroidPrefab;

[SerializeField] 
private float _spawnInterval = 0.125f;

[SerializeField] 
private int _maxObjects;

private bool _canStart = true;

// However your player calls this method
public void StartSpawn()
{
    // Only start spawning if there is no other spawn routine already running
    if(_canStart) StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}

private IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    // Just in case ignore if another routine is already running
    if(!_canStart) yield break;

    // block concurrent routines
    _canStart = false;

    var interval = new WaitForSeconds(_spawnInterval);

    for(var i = 0; i < _maxObjects; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(_asteroidObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        // yield makes Unity pause this routine and render the frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        // Then since we yield return another IEnumerator in thi case WaitForSconds
        // it results exactly in this: Holds here for given seconds and then goes to the next iteration 
        yield return interval;
    }

    // re-enable the StartSpawn
    _canStart = true;
}
```

Then in case you additionally also want to automatically start spawning in the beginning you can simply call it in

```
private void Start()
{
    StartSpawn();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic works like a treat.  2 minor adjustments for anybody wanting to use this

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _asteroidPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _spawnInterval = 0.125f;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _maxObjects;

    private bool _canStart = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartSpawn();
    }
    // However your player calls this method
    public void StartSpawn()
    {
        // Only start spawning if there is no other spawn routine already running
        if (_canStart) StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }

    private IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        // Just in case ignore if another routine is already running
        if (!_canStart) yield break;

        // block concurrent routines
        _canStart = false;

        var interval = new WaitForSeconds(_spawnInterval);

        for (var i = 0; i < _maxObjects; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(_asteroidPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            // yield makes Unity pause this routine and render the frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            // Then since we yield return another IEnumerator in thi case WaitForSconds
            // it results exactly in this: Holds here for given seconds and then goes to the next iteration 
            yield return interval;
        }
        // re-enable the StartSpawn
        _canStart = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i` should not be a class field. See my updated answer (was just a typo ;) missing `var`)

Comment: Thanks derHugo.  Much appreciated.